# Can't create tag for Pro*C

Tags: support, tags

When I try to create the tag `pro-c` for [Pro*C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pro*C), I am told:

> You are attempting to create the tag pro-c ; however the tag proc already exists!

`proc` indeed exists but it is [a Ruby thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/proc).

What tag should I create? `oracle-pro-c`?

Comment: Which question did you want to add it to? A moderator (or possibly a high-rep user) may still be able to create the tag, but only if they know where it belongs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just noticed the [proc-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/proc-sql) tag exists, it covers my need.
Sorry for the noise!